# How could this MW2 round on PlayStation have been hacked?

Tags: call-of-duty-modern-warfare-2, cheats

Now I know about various hacks for games on PCs, or games that run dedicated servers which could easily be modified.

However one day I was playing MW2 on my PlayStation, and I came across a very strange match on Scrapyard where a bunch of players were literally blowing the whole place up constantly. Within 30 seconds, I was already killed 20 times, while the winning team players had more than a hundred kills.

The killcams showed them shooting constantly and the whole map was blowing up every few seconds.

I have some [video footage of that match here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jR1n_zNqxRk).

How is that possible? I thought you could not hack a PS game in that way since you can't control who runs a server.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you witnessed was modding.  Keep in mind, while you cannot control who runs the server there is always a host.  Players can use modded PS3's to force host and then exploit it using alterations to the game itself.

These can including flying, god mode and unlimited AC-130.

Hope this helps